# vector<list<int>> как его использовать

Tags: c++

Скажите пожалуйста, а как использовать `vector` и `list` вместе. Например , я загружаю контейнер с числами, этот контейнер содержит все числа в первом листе , во втором листе у меня другие числа контейнере.
Например `List = 1-2-3-4-5`... 
То есть я добавляю вектор и у меня получается `1[1,2,10,50,30,100]-2[...]-3[]` итд..

Но как мне его загрузить так ? Мне нужно сделать так, потому что потом я указываю номер листа и беру только цифры из этого листа.

Спасибо заранее

Comment: `std::vector` хранит элементы по значению, будь то `std::list` или любой другой `T`. Поэтому разницы между, например, `vector<int>` и `vector<list>` с точки зрения поведения нет никакой. Попробуйте привести [mcve], чтобы было понятно в чем вообще затруднение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае вам надо использовать не `vector<list<int>>`, а `list<vector<int>>` - это более похоже на описанную в вопросе структуру.

Но еще лучше вам подойдет `vector<vector<int>>`, раз вы хотите индексировать контейнеры:

```
vector<vector<int>> v = {
    {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,22},
    {7,8,9,10,11,12},
    {8,22,31,45,52,6,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}
};

for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
{
    cout << "In the vector #" << i <<":";
    for(auto x: v[i])   // Теперь вы берете числа из i-го "листа"
        cout << "  " << x;
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Я не могу использовать двухмерный вектор , потому что я могу хранить  10 разных направлений и в одном направлении может быть 2 точки , а в другом 25.. Поэтому мне нужен лист вектор , потому что именно лист будет хранить количество направлений и в каждом листе будет хранится то количество точек, которое необходимо

Comment: @MishaOstapchuk в чём преимущество list - а перед vector - ом хоть 1 можете назвать?

Comment: Лист быстрее чем вектор .. Но суть не в преимуществе, я не знаю, сколько элементов будет у меня в первом векторе , во втором итд.. То есть двухмерный вектор создает 10х10 матрицу , но у меня может быть 10х3 матрица, другая матрица может быть 10х2 итд.. Мне нужен лист , так как только лист может решить мою задачу или создавать 10 векторов =)

Comment: @MishaOstapchuk В чем проблемы? смотрите, только для вас :) - инициализирую разной длины векторами. Создаете, что хотите - каждый вектор внутри другого может иметь свою длину. И `list` быстрее вектора только в одном - во вставке внутрь. Вам это часто будет надо - вставлять новый элемент не в конец списка, а именно между 891-м и 892-м? :) Учтите только, что кроме `int`, каждый элемент списка будет требовать памяти еще на два указателя...

Comment: @MishaOstapchuk это чушь. В векторе векторов каждый вектор сам по себе и может иметь собственную длину. Не путайте с двумерными массивами.

Answer (score 1):

Можно класть объекты класса list в vector точно так же как и любые друге объекты.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
void print(const std::list<int> &list){
        std::list<int>::const_iterator begin = list.begin();
        std::list<int>::const_iterator end = list.end();

        while(begin != end){
            std::cout << *begin;
            ++begin;
        }
}

int main(){
    std::list<int> list1;
    list1.push_back(1);
    list1.push_back(2);
    list1.push_back(3);

    std::list<int> list2;
    list2.push_back(4);
    list2.push_back(5);
    list2.push_back(6);

    std::vector<std::list<int> > lists;
    lists.push_back(list1);
    lists.push_back(list2);


    for(int i = 0; i < lists.size(); ++i){
        print(lists[i]);
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: В C++11 уже можно не указывать типы, а пользоваться новым ключевым словом `auto`.  Из кода видно что вызывается `begin` для контейнера, значит результатом будет итератор. Поэтому в таких случаях уже "масло-маслянное" с помощью типа указывать что тут итератор :) Также можно улучшить последний `for` с помощью нового `for-each`

Comment: @sys_dev, C++11 это круто, тут и спорить нечего. Только вот используется он далеко не везде. Если бы я был уверен, что компилятор автора его поддерживает, я бы и контейнеры через `{}` инициализировал :) А последний for я хотел изначально так написать `std::for_each(lists.begin(), lists.end(), print);` но решил не пугать)