# Взять элементы из многомерного массива

Tags: c++

Есть некий многомерный массив, с десятью массивами, в каждом массиве N элементов.

```
list<int>route;
vector<list<int>>routes;
route.push_back(.)
routes.push_back(route)

 for(int start = 0 ; start = routes.size();start++)
 {
    for()..
      for()..

 }
```

Например в многомерном массиве 3 массива
[1] = [10,20,30,40,1,20,14]
[2] = [13,23,2,1,4]
[3] = [3,2,1,5,13,2]

Задача: Необходимо вывести массивы с помощью цикла и сравнить элементы только первого массива [10,20,30,40,1,20,14] друг с другом.
С чего начать?

Comment: Можно уточнить в чем проблема? _"Как правильно построить логику?"_ это слишком общий вопрос.

Comment: Проблема ведь описана , я не могу понять, как взять элементы из первого листа , потом взять элементы из второго листа , рассматривая элементы только лишь в нужном листе

Comment: [в этом примере](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/549841/191211) лист распечатывается. Можно аналогичным образом обработать его содержимое как-нибудь иначе

Comment: Иначе -  это хорошо=)

Answer (score 1):

```
for(auto l: routes) 
{
    for(auto i: l)
        cout << i << "  ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Это вывести. Сравнить - что вы хотите узнать? Все ли они одинаковы? Отсортировать? Что именно - поясните. Если проверить, что все одинаковы, например - то надо два итератора (потому что - см. ниже - `list` крайне неэффективная структура), примерно так:

```
auto i = l.begin(), j = i;
++j;
for(;j != l.end(); ++j, ++i)
{
    if (*i != *j) { /* Соседние элементы не равны */ }
    // Или if (*i == *j) { /* Соседние элементы равны */ }
}
```

Если нужно не это - поясните понятнее, что понимается под

> сравнить элементы массива друг с другом

То самое примечание: вас поджидает сюрприз, о котором вам говорили - `list` крайне неэффективен для всяких сортировок и т.п. - вы даже обратиться но номеру элемента в нем просто так не можете - это операция с эффективностью `O(N)`. Надо было брать `vector<vector<int>>`, но, с другой стороны, лучше запоминается то, к чему приходишь сам, набив пару шишек :)

Кстати, в `vector<vector<int>> v` к `m`-му элементу элементу `n`-го вектора можно обращаться просто как к `v[n][m]` - понятно, следя, чтоб индексы были корректными... С `list` так нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Если надо сравнить чтобы узнать одинаковые или нет?! Если да , то берем в первом и сравниваем со вторым. Если порядок во втором не важен. То, берем с первого и ищем во втором.